# How to convert complex nested JSON data to a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe, datatable

Here is the part of JSON data which I need to flatten completely in Pandas dataframe in order to use the data to my needs.

```
{"meta":{"status":"COMPLETED","start_date":"2021-02-18T00:00:00.000Z","end_date":"2021-02-18T23:59:59.999Z","count":185},"data":[{"search_id":11214891,"document_id":"1RfsisOXR6qNW81IR6C9BnYXYzU","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T17:45:21.231Z","document_url":"https://www.challenges.fr/immobilier/paris-remporte-son-bras-de-fer-face-a-airbnb_751784","document_authors":[{"name":"Nicolas Meunier"}],"document_title":"Paris remporte son bras de fer face à Airbnb","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"fr","document_key_phrases":["locations touristiques","résidence secondaire","Cour de cassation","pénurie de logements","local commercial","plateforme","importante victoire","Ville de Paris","logement","changement d'usage très contraignant","décision","autorisation municipale","Paris","locations de résidences principales","bailleur","réglementation","Airbnb","place des mécanismes de compensation similaires","dispositif d'autorisation préalable","autres villes françaises","compensation","millions d'euros d'amendes","ville","euros"],"source_name":"Challenges.fr","source_country_code":"fr","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":2095836,"source_reach_desktop":661063,"source_reach_mobile":1434773,"source_ave":19386.48,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[{"endOffset":716,"name":"Booking.com","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.9235276019904946,"polarities":[{"label":"NEU","score":0.07647239800950542},{"label":"POS","score":0.9235276019904946},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":705}]}]},{"search_id":11214891,"document_id":"lwfznm8K0yV2TGSY8sFO5E2ZazQ","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T16:45:21.487Z","document_url":"https://fr.finance.yahoo.com/actualites/paris-remporte-bras-fer-face-174521120.html","document_authors":[],"document_title":"Paris remporte son bras de fer face à Airbnb","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"fr","document_key_phrases":["Cour de cassation","locations touristiques","Airbnb","local commercial","réglementation conforme","Ville de Paris","résidences secondaires","Paris","autorisation municipale","bras de fer face","nuitées","changement d'usage très contraignant","locations de résidences principales","pénurie de logements","plateforme","dispositif d'autorisation préalable","bailleur","bras","appartement","logement","durée inférieure","courte durée","suite","Alexandre Bompard","génération de managers Bompard"],"source_name":"Yahoo Finance France","source_country_code":"fr","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":306865,"source_reach_desktop":306865,"source_reach_mobile":0,"source_ave":2838.5,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[{"endOffset":820,"name":"Booking.com","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5745349675201228,"polarities":[{"label":"NEU","score":0.4254650324798772},{"label":"POS","score":0.5745349675201228},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":809}]}]},{"search_id":11214891,"document_id":"JEcrdtSVkSH6CmbwVZM9ifS4vmo","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T16:23:29.593Z","document_url":"https://www.notretemps.com/high-tech/actualites/locations-touristiques-de-type-airbnb-afp-202102,i238140","document_authors":[{"name":"AFP"}],"document_title":"Locations touristiques de type Airbnb: les règles de la Ville de Paris validées par la justice française","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"fr","document_key_phrases":["résidence secondaire","pénurie de logements","locations","local commercial","importante victoire","Ville de Paris","logement","changement d'usage très contraignant","décision","locations de résidences principales","plateforme","bailleur","autorisation municipale","Cour de cassation","millions d'euros d'amendes","Paris","place des mécanismes de compensation similaires","dispositif d'autorisation préalable","compensation","autres villes françaises","Airbnb","ville","euros","affaire","Ian Brossat","M. Brossat"],"source_name":"Notretemps.com","source_country_code":"fr","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":2160908,"source_reach_desktop":849854,"source_reach_mobile":1311054,"source_ave":19988.4,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[{"endOffset":719,"name":"Booking.com","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.9235276019904946,"polarities":[{"label":"NEU","score":0.07647239800950542},{"label":"POS","score":0.9235276019904946},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":708}]}]},{"search_id":9086323,"document_id":"R8KxzowCyRQJGiy8h1mNJQiovhc","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T23:35:19.169Z","document_url":"https://news.mt.co.kr/mtview.php?no=2021021014402985119&VN","document_authors":[],"document_title":"“송도에 가면 세계로 통한다”…스타트업 ‘글로벌 등용문’ 활짝","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ko","document_key_phrases":["글로벌 멤버십","스타트업","미팅을","지난해","글로벌 등용문","해외진출 기회를","해외진출 가능성을","역할이 가장","이들 스타트업의 네트워크","해외진출 전략을","인천스타트업파크 신한스퀘어브릿지","글로벌 유니콘","디지털 글로벌","글로벌 멤버십에","글로벌 시장을","글로벌 프로그램","이중 글로벌","관련 업무나","대표적인 글로벌","위치한 인천스타트업파크","스타트업들은 글로벌","산업혁명 관련","미국의 대표적인","인천스타트업파크는 글로벌","인천 송도에","현지 기관의","현지 시장에","현지 액셀러레이터","구체화하는데 현지","국내외 투자유치부터","국내 대표","대표는","국내외 파트너와","외국생활 경험이"],"source_name":"Money Today","source_country_code":"kr","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":8333732,"source_reach_desktop":4335311,"source_reach_mobile":3998421,"source_ave":77087.02,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"u9cTCKixVat-chth8e1m1gD3cfQ","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T05:15:00.430Z","document_url":"https://www.excite.co.jp/news/article/Prtimes_2021-02-18-3373-218/","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["大手総合旅行ブランド","prtimes","国際比較調査","ステイホーム率","世界16地域","エクスペディア","有給休暇","新型コロナウイルス感染症","2020発表","コロナ禍"],"source_name":"エキサイト","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Tokyo","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":22563177,"source_reach_desktop":4572134,"source_reach_mobile":17991043,"source_ave":208709.39,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"KO9oHihWN_5IlSDu-7Jd78HV13Y","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T05:16:00.026Z","document_url":"https://www.jiji.com/jc/article?k=000000218.000003373&g=prt","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","世界16地域","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","コロナ禍","co","新型コロナウイルス","回答","休暇"],"source_name":"時事ドットコム","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Tokyo","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":13596998,"source_reach_desktop":5133231,"source_reach_mobile":8463767,"source_ave":125772.23,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":2724,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEG","score":0},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553}]},"startOffset":2717}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"WRx-0Uu3IuIPKRCh6mySeZAOCqo","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T05:28:35.955Z","document_url":"https://president.jp/ud/pressrelease/602df8337765611611000000","document_authors":[],"document_title":"[エクスペディア・ジャパン]\nエクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","エクスペディア・ジャパン","コロナ禍","co","新型コロナウイルス","回答","休暇"],"source_name":"President Online","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":12523412,"source_reach_desktop":2317254,"source_reach_mobile":10206158,"source_ave":115841.56,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":2722,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":2715}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"0drNNEKrgZq-6m6H7kP49NbB_RI","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T06:05:47.612Z","document_url":"https://news.infoseek.co.jp/article/prtimes_000000218_000003373/","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","prtimes","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","png","https","コロナ禍","co","休暇"],"source_name":"Infoseekニュース","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":6261392,"source_reach_desktop":1835452,"source_reach_mobile":4425940,"source_ave":57917.88,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":3874,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":3867}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"CaAjnxIGRU5UVpSPg4lGTuMqa10","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T02:00:15.567Z","document_url":"https://news.nicovideo.jp/watch/nw8958960","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","大手総合旅行ブランド","世界16地域","エクスペディア","有給休暇","コロナ禍","co","新型コロナウイルス","回答","休暇"],"source_name":"ニコニコニュース","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":7830856,"source_reach_desktop":1193706,"source_reach_mobile":6637150,"source_ave":72435.42,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":3031,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":3024}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"kBqtzavznHaMksy0s8dSzYITD-I","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T05:55:58.996Z","document_url":"https://toyokeizai.net/ud/pressrelease/602dfc4b7765619938420000","document_authors":[],"document_title":"[ エクスペディア・ジャパン ]\n  \nエクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","prtimes","世界16地域","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","png","https","コロナ禍","休暇"],"source_name":"東洋経済オンライン","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":25423431,"source_reach_desktop":4800460,"source_reach_mobile":20622971,"source_ave":235166.74,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":3900,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEG","score":0},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553}]},"startOffset":3893}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"fIwnWI8wEJcnO6UDOMQWNUoWeXA","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T05:57:28.940Z","document_url":"https://news.jorudan.co.jp/docs/news/detail.cgi?newsid=PT000218A000003373","document_authors":[{"name":"ジョルダンソクラニュース"}],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下 - ジョルダンソクラニュース","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","prtimes","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","png","https","コロナ禍","co","休暇"],"source_name":"ジョルダンニュース!","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Tokyo","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":101943,"source_reach_desktop":19745,"source_reach_mobile":82198,"source_ave":942.97,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":3873,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":3866}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"3XPYggMo53SiEPgKv7cr32ZVPt0","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T02:00:31.314Z","document_url":"https://www.fnn.jp/articles/-/145813","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","世界16地域","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","コロナ禍","co","新型コロナウイルス","回答","休暇"],"source_name":"FNN.jp","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":19104460,"source_reach_desktop":2316738,"source_reach_mobile":16787722,"source_ave":176716.26,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":2733,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":2726}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"kwo3oWt-cwP5CCIoWZz05Jn8vX8","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T06:02:51.630Z","document_url":"https://straightpress.jp/company_news/detail?pr=000000218.000003373","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","prtimes","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","https","コロナ禍","co","新型コロナウイルス","休暇"],"source_name":"Straight Press","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":149829,"source_reach_desktop":18477,"source_reach_mobile":131352,"source_ave":1385.92,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":3108,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":3101}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"YjUlh1lkUO5hkoQrP84lul8wdMU","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T05:49:00.620Z","document_url":"https://www.sankei.com/economy/news/210218/prl2102180449-n1.html","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","世界16地域","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","コロナ禍","co","新型コロナウイルス","回答","休暇"],"source_name":"産経ニュース","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":13170608,"source_reach_desktop":3142330,"source_reach_mobile":10028278,"source_ave":121828.12,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":2736,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEG","score":0},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553}]},"startOffset":2729}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"SGVwE1byjL_CaH5jVYxR0mpZiG8","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T08:00:29.479Z","document_url":"https://dime.jp/company_news/detail/?pr=776376","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","prtimes","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","png","https","コロナ禍","co","休暇"],"source_name":"@DIME","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":7164764,"source_reach_desktop":1750326,"source_reach_mobile":5414438,"source_ave":66274.07,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":3862,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEG","score":0},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553}]},"startOffset":3855}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"rCTpBa-tLgT3iqdRrKAYCZk_JwM","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T05:16:59.099Z","document_url":"https://news.biglobe.ne.jp/economy/0218/prt_210218_7925462506.html","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","prtimes","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","png","https","コロナ禍","co","休暇"],"source_name":"Biglobe ニュース","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":7778695,"source_reach_desktop":318393,"source_reach_mobile":7460302,"source_ave":71952.93,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":4201,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEG","score":0},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553}]},"startOffset":4194}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"tK9pxNsmQ2V8vQXt4TAA3SxSIyY","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T02:00:09.254Z","document_url":"https://prtimes.jp/main/html/rd/p/000000218.000003373.html","document_authors":[{"name":"エクスペディア・ジャパン"}],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","エクスペディア","有給休暇","有給休暇取得日数","日本人","コロナ禍","co","新型コロナウイルス","回答","休暇"],"source_name":"PR TIMES","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":16474017,"source_reach_desktop":4172239,"source_reach_mobile":12301778,"source_ave":152384.66,"document_social_echo_twitter":9,"document_social_echo_facebook":18,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":3252,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":3245}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"tjm4T568m5J5pYUPWqD5wqJCqSI","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T09:24:31.845Z","document_url":"https://gendai.ismedia.jp/ud/pressrelease/602dfc3b77656191f7460000","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","世界16地域","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","コロナ禍","co","新型コロナウイルス","回答","休暇"],"source_name":"現代ビジネス","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Tokyo","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":13628949,"source_reach_desktop":4326055,"source_reach_mobile":9302894,"source_ave":126067.78,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":2709,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553},{"label":"NEG","score":0}]},"startOffset":2702}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"-pGOLA8nUcxfC91Hn_xiCv1WZKg","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T07:05:35.347Z","document_url":"https://dime.jp/genre/1084979/","document_authors":[],"document_title":"定着するか？コロナ禍で注目される旅の新形態「ステイケーション」","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["ステイケーション","エクスペディア","予約","ランキング","旅行","海外旅行","旅行スタイル","ランクイン","ホテル予約","旅行予約"],"source_name":"@DIME","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":7164764,"source_reach_desktop":1750326,"source_reach_mobile":5414438,"source_ave":66274.07,"document_social_echo_twitter":5,"document_social_echo_facebook":1,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]},{"search_id":9086309,"document_id":"xeNqsejhJ2mtqT9SdEAk0U01CII","document_publish_date":"2021-02-18T21:29:16.917Z","document_url":"https://news.toremaga.com/release/others/1784791.html","document_authors":[],"document_title":"エクスペディア 世界16地域 有給休暇・国際比較調査 2020発表！コロナ禍で有給休暇の取得が世界的に低下","document_sentiment":"neutral","document_language_code":"ja","document_key_phrases":["expedia","prtimes","世界16地域","エクスペディア","有給休暇","日本人","png","https","コロナ禍","休暇"],"source_name":"とれまがニュース","source_country_code":"jp","source_subregion":"Undef","source_information_type":"news","source_reach":4714,"source_reach_desktop":4179,"source_reach_mobile":535,"source_ave":43.6,"document_social_echo_twitter":0,"document_social_echo_facebook":0,"document_social_echo_reddit":0,"goal":[{"name":"Appeal"},{"name":"Credibility"},{"name":"Fit"},{"name":"Purchase Intent"},{"name":"Trust"}],"entity_level_sentiment":[{"name":"expedia","occurrences":[{"endOffset":3988,"name":"Expedia","sentiment":{"discrete":"POS","numeric":0.5066692835224845,"polarities":[{"label":"POS","score":0.5066692835224845},{"label":"NEG","score":0},{"label":"NEU","score":0.49333071647751553}]},"startOffset":3981}]},{"name":"booking","occurrences":[]}]}
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid...

Comment: Your json string is missing `]}` at the end, you need to provide which column you need or we can't help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.read_json()` ([ref 1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)) or `pandas.json_normalize()` ([ref 2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)) but you need to first correct your code to be a proper JSON.